# Modifying data in threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have a class with the following structure:

```
class Nginx_sender
{
    private:
        std::vector<std::string> mMessagesBuffer;
        boost::mutex mMutex;

       void SendMessage(const std::string &msg)
       {
           mMutex.lock();
           mMessagesBuffer.push_back(msg);
           mMutex.unlock();

           std::cout << "Vector size: " << mMessagesBuffer.size() << std::endl;
       }

       void NewThreadFunction()
       {
          while(true) {
            mMutex.lock();
            if (mMessagesBuffer.size() >= 1) std::cout << ">=1\n";
            mMutex.unlock();

            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(200));
          }
       }
};

int main()
{
   Nginx_sender *NginxSenderHandle;
   boost::thread sender(boost::bind(&Nginx_sender::NewThreadFunction, &NginxSenderHandle));
   // ...
}
```

`NewThreadFunction` is running in new thread and it checks the size of `mMessagesBuffer`. Now I call anywhere in `main` function: `NginxSenderHandle->SendMessage("Test");`

This shows up: `Vector size: 1` first time, `2` second time etc.

But! In `NewThreadFunction` it's always == 0. Why could it be?

Comment: You should only check the buffer size while holding the mutex, as in, print or save to a local variable the value of `mMessagesBuffer.size()`. See what happens then.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you haven't accidentally created two `Nginx_sender`s? Post a complete `main` which exhibits the behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet compiler is caching some of mMessagesBuffer internals in thread-local cache. Try adding 'volatile' keyword to mMessagesBuffer to disable such optimizations.

Comment: `volatile` shouldn't be necessary when mutex is used.

Comment: @Gene Compiler doesn't know about mutexes, does it?

Comment: @Ockonal It doesn't. But mutex knows how to instruct compiler to not break it.

Comment: @user1415080 Are you sure mutex won't add memory barriers?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837699/are-mutex-lock-functions-sufficient-without-volatile and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616093/does-presence-of-mutex-help-getting-rid-of-volatile-key-word

Answer (score 2):

You are most probably creating another copy of Nginx_sender when you bind it.  Do you really need to reference NginxSenderHandle before passing it to bind() (it's already a pointer)?   http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_member_pointers